# php wildcard search for mixed string with a file path and details

Tags: php, string, search, pattern-matching, wildcard

In my php program i need to search a mixed string having a file path and some details about it with a pattern with or without wildcards, if this pattern matches with the string then it should return true otherwise false.

example:

```
$string="us01     /remote/ecishome/gussman/Sol_10         TEST    WILLIAMS   us01-000018     us01-000019     04/19/2012      04/19/2012      05/20/2012      Expired"
```

if `$pattern= "/remote/*/guss*"` it should match true or if `$pattern=will*` it should return true or if `$pattern="/remote/ecishome/gussman/Sol_10"` then also it should return true.

can anyone please suggest me how can i do this. Any help in this is really appreciable.

Now i'm using `fnmatch()` for this but not able meet the requirement.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable job for fnmatch(). What goes wrong when you try to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using below code but it is not working,  if(fnmatch($pattern,$string,FNM_NOESCAPE|FNM_PATHNAME|FNM_CASEFOLD))
                                        {
                                                $match++;

                                        }

Comment: and my input patterns were not escaped with '\' before wildcard, as it is end user input data.

Comment: What does happen when you use it? Do you get an error? No match? The wrong match? Does it match for some patterns but not others?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

good regex info site: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html)

Answer (score 0):

To match the `/remote/*/guss*` pattern you could use the following regex:

```
/\/remote\/[\w]*\/guss[\S]*/
```

To match `will*` you could use the following regex:

```
/will[\S]*/i
```

To match `/remote/ecishome/gussman/Sol_10` you could use the following regex:

```
/\/remote\/ecishome\/gussman\/Sol_10/
```

You could use these regex patterns using `preg_match`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, but i need a single solution irrespective of the pattern.